SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected "," in typescript file
i have 2 files, one is Helper.ts that has some functions and Helper.spec.ts that is the test file for the Helper.ts using jest.
I was using this with pure javascript but i changed it to typescript, i installed types/jest , my jest file was Helper.test.js and i changed it to Helper.spec.ts, since then i'm having this error, can someone help me to figure it out?
Error print
Here is a part of my Helper.ts:
export class Helper {
  static isDefined(value: any): boolean {
    const s = value;
    const status = s !== null && s !== undefined;
    return status;
  }

  static isNotDefined(value: any): boolean {
    return !this.isDefined(value);
  }
}

And here is a part of my Helper.spec.ts:
import { Helper } from './Helper';

describe('Helpers tests', () => {
  test('isDefined deve retornar true se o valor estiver definido', () => {
    expect(Helper.isDefined('')).toBeTruthy();
    expect(Helper.isDefined(null)).toBeFalsy();
    expect(Helper.isDefined(undefined)).toBeFalsy();
    expect(Helper.isDefined(0)).toBeTruthy();
    expect(Helper.isDefined('hello')).toBeTruthy();
  });

  test('isNotDefined deve retornar true se o valor não estiver definido', () => {
    expect(Helper.isNotDefined('')).toBeFalsy();
    expect(Helper.isNotDefined(null)).toBeTruthy();
    expect(Helper.isNotDefined(undefined)).toBeTruthy();
  });

}

That's my tsconfig.json, i dont know if it is helpful
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsxImportSource": "vue",
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true
  },
  "types": ["@types/node", "@types/vue", "webpack-env"],
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts", "src/**/*.tsx", "src/**/*.vue"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}


I don't have any jest configuration in my package.json, just the :
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.12",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^7.6.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^7.6.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",

I checked the logic and i couldn't see anything wrong, maybe i'm missing something

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular How do I ask a good question? Please post code, error messages, console output, markup, data, data structures, and other textual information as text, not just as a picture of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Solution :
I was able to fix the problem by installing: @babel/preset-typescript
And creating a babel.config.js file with this configuration:
module.exports = { presets: [
['@babel/preset-env', { targets: { node: 'current' } }],
'@babel/preset-typescript',
], };


Is it possible that you might be missing a jest.config.json file?
It should look something like this:
{
  "moduleFileExtensions": ["js", "json", "ts"],
  "rootDir": "src",
  "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
  "maxWorkers": "100%",
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": [
      "ts-jest", {
        "isolatedModules": true
      }
    ]
  },
  "collectCoverageFrom": [
    "**/*.(t|j)s"
  ],
  "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
  "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": ["index.ts", ".module.ts", "main.ts"],
  "testEnvironment": "node",
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "@/(.*)": "<rootDir>/$1"
  }
}

Keep in mind that I posted a sample from a NodeJS server; in your case it's possible that other options are needed.

I tried to configure a jest.config.json following the jest documentation but i had the same error :/
